# Rails: Provide default value for the disabled select helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, default

I have a select helper as seen below, I have disabled it and would like give "1" as default value, but couldnt find how?

```
<%= f.select :fuel_incl, [[t('shared.incl'),'1'],[t('shared.notInc'),'0']], {}, {class: "Select-control u-sizeFull fuel_incl", :disabled => true} %>
```

It is disabled so it should select 1 as default.

**EDIT**

I see that it works from the console;

```
<select class="Select-control u-sizeFull fuel_incl" disabled="disabled" name="boat[fuel_incl]" id="boat_fuel_incl">
<option selected="selected" value="1">Included</option>
<option value="0">Not Included</option></select>
```

but it does not send as params, when I take out disable true and select value send the form, it works..

**EDIT2**

anyways, I have solved it by giving only one select value as;

```
<%= f.select :fuel_incl, 
             [[t('shared.incl'),'1']], 
             { selected: '1' }, 
             { class: "Select-control u-sizeFull fuel_incl" } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `selected` option:

```
<%= f.select :fuel_incl, 
             [[t('shared.incl'),'1'],[t('shared.notInc'),'0']], 
             { selected: '1' }, 
             { class: "Select-control u-sizeFull fuel_incl", disabled: true } %>
```